# format JSON object into array like structure

Tags: python, json

I am quite new to Python but trying to do some machine learning with it.

My problem is to format a received JSON object into an array like structure to submit this to my predictor function of the ML model.

JSON object looks like when I do a print of it

```
{u'CRIM': 0.62739, u'ZN': 0, u'B': 395.62, u'LSTAT': 8.47, u'AGE': 56.5, u'TAX': 307, u'RAD': 4, u'CHAS': 0, u'NOX': 0.538, u'MEDV': 19.9, u'RM': 5.834, u'INDUS': 8.14, u'PTRATIO': 21, u'DIS': 4.4986}
```

what i need is

```
[0.62739, 0, 395.62, 8.47, 56.5, 307, 4, 0, 0.538, 19.9, 5.834, 8.14, 21, 4.4986]
```

Can anybody help here
thanks
Peter

Comment: the problem with what you are trying to do is that the order of the key/values is not guaranteed by json specifications in an object.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
json_var = {u'CRIM': 0.62739, u'ZN': 0, u'B': 395.62, u'LSTAT': 8.47, u'AGE': 56.5, u'TAX': 307, u'RAD': 4, u'CHAS': 0, u'NOX': 0.538, u'MEDV': 19.9, u'RM': 5.834, u'INDUS': 8.14, u'PTRATIO': 21, u'DIS': 4.4986}
value_array = json_var.values()
```

Comment: @PeterHIRT your welcome, if my answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
d = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
num_list = d.values()

# num_list = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: When I was writing this, no other answer was there